# Shell extension doesn't work in Windows-Explorer but works in other programs?

Tags: windows, com, atl, shell-extensions

I made shell extension (implementing `IContextMenu`, `IShellExtInit`, `IExtractIcon` & `IPersistFile`) using ATL, "by the book".

The funny thing is that all is good in some files-managers such as "Total Commander" & "Free Commander", but completely fail in Windows' Explorer:

---

When I right click on my registered file (say `*.000`) in TC ("Total Commander"), the extension works: I see it in my logs and in the context menu: the entry with its icon appear.

But if I use Win-Explorer, nothing happens! **no log entry comes up**, no evidence in the context menu - nothing! even a complete PC restart doesn't help.

I of course registered the `ShellEx\MyX\ContextMenuHandlers` and `ShellEx\IconHandler`keys, as well as the Explorer's `...\Shell Extensions\Approved\`, and they all point to my `CLSID`.
I use Windows 7.

What do I miss here ?

Comment: 64/32 bit? If your OS is 64 bit, the Explorer will be 64 bit as well, and all your shell extensions will have to be 64 bit as well. Looks like current version of Total Commander is 32 bit only.

Comment: @SevaTitov: That sounds right. I use 64 bit OS but compiled and registered 32 bit app. So instead InprocServer32, what key should I create for 64 bit DLL ?

Comment: Just compile for 64 bit and regsvr32 this binary. The registry key is still called InprocServer32.

Comment: @SevaTitov: Yes! it works, you're right! I was completely unaware of the [Registry Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and that was the pitfall.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SevaTitov answered my question but as a comment, so for future references for anyone who stumbles upon this issue:

@SevaTitov:

> If your OS is 64 bit, the Explorer will be 64 bit as well, and all your shell extensions will have to be 64 bit as well. Looks like current version of Total Commander is 32 bit only

There's that thing, [Registry Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), that when you're in 32-bit program, it hides ("redirects") the 64-bit reg-entries, and vice versa.

I was confused because in my 32-bit registry-viewer-app I could see those keys, but was unaware that I only see a part of the registry (the 64-bit part has to be seen with a 64-bit viewer like the default regedit.exe in a 64-bit Windows machine)

Comment: It is not [only] about registry. 64-bit Explorer can only load 64-bit DLLs, so it by no chance can use your 32-bit shell extension. You normally have to provide two versions of shell extensions for 64-bit OS, that is 32- and 64-bit versions of the shell extension to match bitness of the hosting process.