# context menu shell extension doesn't appear in explorer

Tags: windows, com, contextmenu, shell-extensions

I have the same problem as described here "[Shell extension doesn't work in Windows-Explorer but works in other programs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7668305/shell-extension-doesnt-work-in-windows-explorer-but-works-in-other-programs)", but it doesn't works only in explorer. OS Windows 7 x64. Dll was compiled as x64 project.

Part of my trace-file when i call context menu in explorer:

```
DllGetClassObject
Factory: Create component
clComponent::QueryInterface: Return pointer to IContextMenu
Factory: Self Destruction
clComponent::QueryInterface: Interface doesn't supported : {00000003-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
clComponent::QueryInterface: Interface doesn't supported : {0000001B-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
clComponent::QueryInterface: Return pointer to IUnknown
clComponent::QueryInterface: Interface doesn't supported : {00000018-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
clComponent::QueryInterface: Interface doesn't supported : {00000019-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}
clComponent::QueryInterface: Interface doesn't supported : {4C1E39E1-E3E3-4296-AA86-EC938D896E92}
clComponent::QueryInterface: Return pointer to IContextMenu
Component: Self Destruction
```

I also implement two interfaces IShellExtInit and IContextMenu.
Maybe I did something wrong in Windows register?.. Could someone write necessary changes in register?

Trace-file after registration 32 and 64 bit dlls:

```
DllMain: dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH

DllRegisterServer
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{7E6025F5-6D2F-4A95-A6FE-E38AF9D1D0E5} : COM Shell Extension
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{7E6025F5-6D2F-4A95-A6FE-E38AF9D1D0E5}\InprocServer32 : C:\COMShellExtension32.dll
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{7E6025F5-6D2F-4A95-A6FE-E38AF9D1D0E5}\ProgID : COMShellExtension.ShellExtension.1
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{7E6025F5-6D2F-4A95-A6FE-E38AF9D1D0E5}\VersionIndependentProgID : COMShellExtension.ShellExtension
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\COMShellExtension.ShellExtension : COM Shell Extension
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\COMShellExtension.ShellExtension\CLSID : {7E6025F5-6D2F-4A95-A6FE-E38AF9D1D0E5}
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\COMShellExtension.ShellExtension\CurVer : COMShellExtension.ShellExtension.1
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\COMShellExtension.ShellExtension.1 : COM Shell Extension
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\COMShellExtension.ShellExtension.1\CLSID : {7E6025F5-6D2F-4A95-A6FE-E38AF9D1D0E5}
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{7E6025F5-6D2F-4A95-A6FE-E38AF9D1D0E5} : COM Shell Extension
RegisterServer: S_OK

DllMain: dwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH

DllRegisterServer
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{7E6025F5-6D2F-4A95-A6FE-E38AF9D1D0E5} : COM Shell Extension
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{7E6025F5-6D2F-4A95-A6FE-E38AF9D1D0E5}\InprocServer32 : C:\COMShellExtension64.dll
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{7E6025F5-6D2F-4A95-A6FE-E38AF9D1D0E5}\ProgID : COMShellExtension.ShellExtension.1
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{7E6025F5-6D2F-4A95-A6FE-E38AF9D1D0E5}\VersionIndependentProgID : COMShellExtension.ShellExtension
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\COMShellExtension.ShellExtension : COM Shell Extension
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\COMShellExtension.ShellExtension\CLSID : {7E6025F5-6D2F-4A95-A6FE-E38AF9D1D0E5}
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\COMShellExtension.ShellExtension\CurVer : COMShellExtension.ShellExtension.1
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\COMShellExtension.ShellExtension.1 : COM Shell Extension
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\COMShellExtension.ShellExtension.1\CLSID : {7E6025F5-6D2F-4A95-A6FE-E38AF9D1D0E5}
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\*\shellex\ContextMenuHandlers\{7E6025F5-6D2F-4A95-A6FE-E38AF9D1D0E5} : COM Shell Extension
RegisterServer: S_OK
```

My Registry.cpp

```
//
// Registry.cpp
//

#include <objbase.h>
#include <Shlobj.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include "trace_tool.h"
#include "Registry.h"



////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Internal helper functions prototypes
//

// Set the given key and its value.
BOOL setKeyAndValue(const wchar_t* pszPath,
                    const wchar_t* szSubkey,
                    const wchar_t* szValue) ;

// Convert a CLSID into a char string.
void CLSIDtochar(const CLSID& clsid, 
                 wchar_t* szCLSID,
                 int length) ;

// Delete szKeyChild and all of its descendents.
LONG recursiveDeleteKey(HKEY hKeyParent, const wchar_t* szKeyChild) ;

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Constants
//

// Size of a CLSID as a string
const int CLSID_STRING_SIZE = 39 ;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Public function implementation
//

//
// Register the component in the registry.
//
HRESULT RegisterServer(HMODULE hModule,            // DLL module handle
                       const CLSID& clsid,         // Class ID
                       const wchar_t* szFriendlyName, // Friendly Name
                       const wchar_t* szVerIndProgID, // Programmatic
                       const wchar_t* szProgID)       //   IDs
{
    // Get server location.
    wchar_t szModule[512] ;
    DWORD dwResult =
        ::GetModuleFileName(hModule, 
                            szModule,
                            sizeof(szModule)/sizeof(wchar_t)) ;
    assert(dwResult != 0) ;

    // Convert the CLSID into a char.
    wchar_t szCLSID[CLSID_STRING_SIZE] = {0};
    CLSIDtochar(clsid, szCLSID, CLSID_STRING_SIZE) ;

    // Build the key CLSID\\{...}
    wchar_t szKey[64] ;
    wcscpy(szKey, L"CLSID\\") ;
    wcscat(szKey, szCLSID) ;

    // Add the CLSID to the registry.
    setKeyAndValue(szKey, NULL, szFriendlyName) ;

    // Add the server filename subkey under the CLSID key.
    setKeyAndValue(szKey, L"InprocServer32", szModule) ;

    // Add the ProgID subkey under the CLSID key.
    setKeyAndValue(szKey, L"ProgID", szProgID) ;

    // Add the version-independent ProgID subkey under CLSID key.
    setKeyAndValue(szKey, L"VersionIndependentProgID", szVerIndProgID) ;

    // Add the version-independent ProgID subkey under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.
    setKeyAndValue(szVerIndProgID, NULL, szFriendlyName) ; 
    setKeyAndValue(szVerIndProgID, L"CLSID", szCLSID) ;
    setKeyAndValue(szVerIndProgID, L"CurVer", szProgID) ;

    // Add the versioned ProgID subkey under HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT.
    setKeyAndValue(szProgID, NULL, szFriendlyName) ;
    setKeyAndValue(szProgID, L"CLSID", szCLSID) ;

    // context-menu hendler
    setKeyAndValue(L"*\\shellex\\ContextMenuHandlers", szCLSID, szFriendlyName);

    trace("RegisterServer: S_OK");
    return S_OK ;
}

//
// Remove the component from the registry.
//
LONG UnregisterServer(const CLSID& clsid,         // Class ID
                      const wchar_t* szVerIndProgID, // Programmatic
                      const wchar_t* szProgID)       //   IDs
{
    // Convert the CLSID into a char.
    wchar_t szCLSID[CLSID_STRING_SIZE] = {0};
    CLSIDtochar(clsid, szCLSID, CLSID_STRING_SIZE) ;

    // Build the key CLSID\\{...}
    wchar_t szKey[64] = {0};
    wcscpy(szKey, L"CLSID\\") ;
    wcscat(szKey, szCLSID) ;

    // Delete the CLSID Key - CLSID\{...}
    LONG lResult = recursiveDeleteKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, szKey) ;
    assert((lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS) || (lResult == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)) ; // Subkey may not exist.

    // Delete the version-independent ProgID Key.
    lResult = recursiveDeleteKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, szVerIndProgID) ;
    assert((lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS) || (lResult == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)) ; // Subkey may not exist.

    // Delete the ProgID key.
    lResult = recursiveDeleteKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, szProgID) ;
    assert((lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS) || (lResult == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)) ; // Subkey may not exist.

    // Delete the context-menu hendler
    //lResult = recursiveDeleteKey(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT, szProgID) ;
    //assert((lResult == ERROR_SUCCESS) || (lResult == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)) ; // Subkey may not exist.


    trace("UnregisterServer: S_OK");
    return S_OK ;
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Internal helper functions
//

// Convert a CLSID to a char string.
void CLSIDtochar(const CLSID& clsid, wchar_t* szCLSID, int length)
{
    assert(length >= CLSID_STRING_SIZE) ;
    // Get CLSID
    LPOLESTR wszCLSID = NULL ;
    HRESULT hr = StringFromCLSID(clsid, &wszCLSID) ;
    assert(SUCCEEDED(hr)) ;

    //// Covert from wide characters to non-wide.
    //wcstombs(szCLSID, wszCLSID, length) ;

    wcsncpy(szCLSID, wszCLSID, length - 1);

    // Free memory.
    CoTaskMemFree(wszCLSID) ;
}

//
// Delete a key and all of its descendents.
//
LONG recursiveDeleteKey(HKEY hKeyParent,           // Parent of key to delete
                        const wchar_t* lpszKeyChild)  // Key to delete
{
    // Open the child.
    HKEY hKeyChild ;
    LONG lRes = RegOpenKeyEx(hKeyParent, lpszKeyChild, 0, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, &hKeyChild);
    if (lRes != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return lRes ;
    }

    // Enumerate all of the decendents of this child.
    FILETIME time ;
    wchar_t szBuffer[256];
    DWORD dwSize = 256 ;
    while (RegEnumKeyEx(hKeyChild, 0, szBuffer, &dwSize, NULL, NULL, NULL, &time) == S_OK)
    {
        // Delete the decendents of this child.
        lRes = recursiveDeleteKey(hKeyChild, szBuffer) ;
        if (lRes != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            // Cleanup before exiting.
            RegCloseKey(hKeyChild) ;
            return lRes;
        }
        dwSize = 256 ;
    }

    // Close the child.
    RegCloseKey(hKeyChild) ;

    // Delete this child.
    return RegDeleteKey(hKeyParent, lpszKeyChild) ;
}

//
// Create a key and set its value.
//   - This helper function was borrowed and modifed from
//     Kraig Brockschmidt's book Inside OLE.
//
BOOL setKeyAndValue(const wchar_t* szKey,
                    const wchar_t* szSubkey,
                    const wchar_t* szValue)
{
    HKEY hKey;
    wchar_t szKeyBuf[1024] = {0};

    // Copy keyname into buffer.
    wcscpy(szKeyBuf, szKey) ;

    // Add subkey name to buffer.
    if (szSubkey != NULL)
    {
        wcscat(szKeyBuf, L"\\") ;
        wcscat(szKeyBuf, szSubkey ) ;
    }


    // Create and open key and subkey.
    long lResult = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT ,
                                  szKeyBuf, 
                                  0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE,
                                  KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, 
                                  &hKey, NULL) ;
    if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        return FALSE ;
    }

    // Set the Value.
    if (szValue != NULL)
    {
        RegSetValueEx(hKey, NULL, 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE *)szValue, (wcslen(szValue)+1) * sizeof(wchar_t) );
        trace(std::wstring(L"HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\\") + szKeyBuf + L" : " + szValue);
    }

    RegCloseKey(hKey) ;
    return TRUE ;
}
```

**Solved!
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\%CLSID%\InprocServer32 : name: "ThreadingModel"  val: "Apartment"**

Comment: Did you try the answer there? It looks to me like the same exact mistake from the other side. You know that you need both 32 and 64 bit versions, right?

Comment: Do I realy need both versions of .dll for 64 bit Windows? If I do, how can I register both dll with the same name and same CLSID?

Comment: The problem is that it works when I click on desktop or in TotalComander(x64), but doesn't works when I click in explorer ...

Comment: The problem is that it works when I click on desktop ----- desktop is explorer. :)))

Comment: There might be something else, but you definitely need both. A 32-bit app cannot load a 64-bit DLL and vice-versa, so Windows provides both 32-bit and 64-bit shell components for things like the Open dialog box. If you only register a 64-bit version, the Open dialog box of a 32-bit app won't show your extension. You use the same CLSID, etc. When you register them, they get registered in different places of the registry. Let's fix the obvious problem first, then we can look for other issues if you sill have problems.

Comment: It still doesn't work when I click on some file, for example, in C:\ directory. Maybe I don't add something to the registry?

Comment: Show your registry settings, I assume your extensions is registred for background, not folder/directory itself.

Comment: Sorry, but how can I show you them? I don't use ATL. I use RegCreateKeyEx() and RegSetValueEx(). You can see changes in register above (in the part of trace-file).

Comment: I have refreshed my post with included Register.cpp file.

Comment: This is a little modified file from book "Inside COM" - D. Rogerson.